# Is there a more preferable way to center align 2 columns in a container?

Tags: css, alignment, flexbox, center

I am designing the "portfolio" section of my website and I am having difficulty finding the 'best' (subjective) way to have a container with 2 columns, center the content that is inside each column similar to [this website's](http://www.chris-cook.net/) "web development" section. I tried using flexbox, but wanted to know if I'm using the best method for what I'm trying to achieve or are there better ways to get the same result?

See my current code in action here: http://codepen.io/muygalan/pen/ZOVQgm

```
See above link for code.
```

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: Questions must include the shortest code **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that you don't really have to use flexbox to achieve this, it's pretty straightforward. [Here's](https://codepen.io/juanferreras/pen/GqPkpA) a working example on codepen using simply `float` and a `media query`. I've assummed you want to achieve the same result than the website you've provided where on mobile both columns stack on top of each other, with the image always being the first; the easiest way to avoid flexbox is to modify a bit your html markup.

I've tried to keep the CSS as slim and straight as possible.

```
.portfolio{
  max-width: 1020px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear: both;
}
.port-col-left,
.port-col-right{
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
@media screen and (min-width:992px){
  .port-col-left,
  .port-col-right{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .portfolio--inverted .port-col-left,
  .portfolio--inverted .port-col-right{
    float: right;
  }
}
```